# Javascript to calculate total Price and Cost?

Tags: javascript

How to rewrite the below script to auto calculate the total price and total cost at the same time ??
Thank you very much for your help & support !

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
function calc(obj) {
    var e = obj.id.toString();
    if (e == 'quantity') {
        x = Number(obj.value);
        y = Number(document.getElementById('unit_price').value);
    } else {
        x = Number(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
        y = Number(obj.value);
    }
    z = x * y ;
    document.getElementById('sub_price').value = z;
    document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<form>
Quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onkeyup="calc(this)" required="required"/>

<br>
Unit Price:<input type="number" id="unit_price" onkeyup="calc(this)" name="unit_price" step="any" value="3"  required="required" />
<br>
    
Total Price:<input  type="number" id="sub_price"  name="sub_price" step="any"  value="" readonly required="required" />

<br><br>
Unit Cost:<input type="number" id="unit_cost" onkeyup="calc(this)" name="unit_cost" step="any" value="2"  required="required" />

<br>
Total Cost:<input  type="number" id="sub_cost"  name="sub_cost" step="any"  value="" readonly required="required" />
    
    

</form>
```

Comment: You don't have an element with id `update`

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate. I assume you will have more than one item

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const totalField = document.getElementById("total")
const itemContainers = [...form.querySelectorAll(".item")];
const calc = (e) => {
  const total = itemContainers.map(item => {
      const qty = +item.querySelector(".quantity").value,
        price = +item.querySelector(".unit_price").value,
        subTotal = qty * price;
      item.querySelector(".sub_price").value = !price || isNaN(price) ? 0 : price.toFixed(2);
      item.querySelector(".sub_cost").value = !subTotal || isNaN(subTotal) ? 0 : subTotal.toFixed(2);
      return subTotal;
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  totalField.value = total.toFixed(2);
};


form.addEventListener("input", calc)
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="item">
    Quantity: <input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" required="required" />

    <br> Unit Price:<input type="number" class="unit_price" name="unit_price" step="any" value="3" required="required" />
    <br> Sub Price:<input type="number" class="sub_price" name="sub_price" step="any" value="" readonly required="required" />

    <br><br> Unit Cost:<input type="number" class="unit_cost" name="unit_cost" step="any" value="2" required="required" />
    <br> Sub Cost:<input type="number" class="sub_cost" name="sub_cost" step="any" value="" readonly required="required" />
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    Quantity: <input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" required="required" />

    <br> Unit Price:<input type="number" class="unit_price" name="unit_price" step="any" value="3" required="required" />
    <br> Sub Price:<input type="number" class="sub_price" name="sub_price" step="any" value="" readonly required="required" />

    <br><br> Unit Cost:<input type="number" class="unit_cost" name="unit_cost" step="any" value="2" required="required" />
    <br> Sub Cost:<input type="number" class="sub_cost" name="sub_cost" step="any" value="" readonly required="required" />
  </div>
  <hr/>
  Total cost: <input id="total" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update your calc function as follows. Hopefully this will work:

```
function calc() {
var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
var unitPrice = Number(document.getElementById('unit_price').value);
var unitCost = Number(document.getElementById('unit_cost').value);
var totalPrice = quantity * unitPrice;
 var totalCost = quantity * unitCost;
document.getElementById('sub_price').value = totalPrice;
document.getElementById('sub_cost').value = totalCost;
document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = totalPrice;

}


<form>
  Quantity: <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" required="required" />
  <br>
  Unit Price: <input type="number" id="unit_price" name="unit_price" step="any" value="3" required="required" />
  <br>
  Total Price: <input type="number" id="sub_price" name="sub_price" step="any" value="" readonly required="required" />
  <br><br>
  Unit Cost: <input type="number" id="unit_cost" name="unit_cost" step="any" value="2" required="required" />
  <br>
  Total Cost: <input type="number" id="sub_cost" name="sub_cost" step="any" value="" readonly required="required" />
</form>

<script>
  
  document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener('input', calc);
  document.getElementById('unit_price').addEventListener('input', calc);
  document.getElementById('unit_cost').addEventListener('input', calc);
  
  
  calc();
</script>
```